# How to hold a http request without failing until response coming in Angular

Tags: angular, http

This is my http API request `this.dashboardServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params)`. API returns a response like after 2 min.In here i am trying to hold my request until reponse coming.But in network tab it shows pending for a long time and it fails. How could i hold my request until response comes.

```
delayForFiveSeconds = () => timer(135000);

getBookingInfo(dateType: string) {
  const delayForFiveSeconds = () => timer(135000);
  const params = [];

  params.push({code: 'dateType', name: dateType});
  params.push({code: 'from', name: '2019-01-01'});
  params.push({code: 'to', name: '2019-01-31'});

  // this.timeout(4000);
  return  this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params);
}
```

In this class i am calling the backend API.

```
export class ServiceHandler {
    getTxnInfo(headers: any[], params: any[]) {
    return this.apiService.get(environment.rm_url + 'rm-analytics-api/dashboard/txn-info', headers, params);
  }
}

getBookingDetails() {
  this.delayForFiveSeconds().subscribe(() => {this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING').subscribe(
    bookings => {
      console.log(bookings);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: you said your service was `this.dashboardServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params)`, but you actually make the code `this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params)`. Could you explain better what you want?

Comment: by the way, welcome to stack overflow! ;)

Comment: "How could i hold my request until response comes." in theory, the `subscribe` should do the trick, unless something is going wrong in the backend.

Comment: I added my service class where i am defining getTxnInfo([], params) function.Actually by backend API call in swagger takes more than 2 min to give the response.Caz of that delay in network tab api call fails

Comment: Therefore i want to hold that API  request without failing until response comes

Answer (score 1):

RxJS has a timeout operator. Probably you can use that to increase the timeout

```
getBookingInfo(dateType: string) {
  ...
  return  this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).pipe(
    timeout(10*60*1000) // 10 minutes
  );
}
```

And then you can update the calling function to

```
getBookingDetails() {
  this.getBookingInfo('BOOKING').subscribe(
    bookings => {
      console.log(bookings);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the timeout operator of `rxjs`, including it in a `pipe` with `timeout`:

```
import { timeout, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';

...
getTxnInfo(headers: any[], params: any[]) {
  this.apiService.get(environment.rm_url + 'rm-analytics-api/dashboard/txn-info', headers, params)
   .pipe(
      timeout(20000),
      catchError(e => {
        return of(null);
      })
    );
}
```

Using it:

```
  this.ServiceHandler.getTxnInfo([], params).subscribe(
    txnInfos => {
      console.log(txnInfos );
  });
```