# Keep the HTTP get request active until get back the response in Angular

Tags: angular, timeout

I am using a HTTP get request which is requesting data and response from backend. But the data is huge and taking a while to prepare the response data and return it back. My get request is getting timeout before it receives the actual OK response. I tried to use `pipe(timeout(30000))` but still connection is not waiting and throwing "Gateway Timeout" error.

```
 public getDatafromServer(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get('URL', {
      headers: any[]
    }).pipe(timeout(30000));
    }
```

And then calling getDatafromServer  function to get the response. I am using reference [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61521294/how-to-hold-a-http-request-without-failing-until-response-coming-in-angular) and several questions but nothing worked in my case.

Comment: i think this timeout is not from angular. this is from backend or from webserver if you are in production mode

Comment: But can we keep our request active while waiting for the response in angular?

Comment: what's the error code you're getting?

Comment: Do you get the data with CURL or Postman? Timeout, which you added works after server response and it doesn't influent to the connection. You should find issue on server site(NGINX, Apache, etc)

Comment: I am getting 504 Gateway timeout error.

Comment: @Nikita, it means I will have to look from backend code and server settings to increase the connection timeout. Actually after getting this request there is some data fetch happening from another system and some data manipulation before sending the response. And this process is taking a bit longer.